# SOAP Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap, yii

SOAP is unable to connect to a https host when launched as a PHP console application
Works fine when launched from browser. But throws SOAPFault everytime it is launched from CLI 
Both use the same .ini file, and the host does not use wsdl.

```
$uid = '****';

$xml_header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parameters>';
$xml_footer = '</parameters>';
$xml_content = '';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_header.$xml_content.$xml_footer);
$options = array(
    "location" => 'https://***/wsedi/services/EDIServiceSoap',
    "uri" => 'https://***/wsedi/services/Send',
    "exceptions" => true,
    'trace' => true,
);

$data = array(
    new SoapParam('***', "Login"),
    new SoapParam('***', "Password"),
    new SoapParam($uid, "Uid"),
    new SoapParam($xml->asXML(), "Params"),
);

$client = new SoapClient(NULL, $options);

try {
    $return = $client->__soapCall("ExecSQL", $data);
    print_r($return);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e->getTrace());
}



array(2) {
      [0] =>
      array(4) {
    'function' =>
    string(11) "__doRequest"
    'class' =>
    string(10) "SoapClient"
    'type' =>
    string(2) "->"
    'args' =>
    array(5) {
      [0] =>
      string(739) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xm
lns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://***/wsedi/services/Send" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xml
ns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schema
s.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org
/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:ExecSQL><Login xsi:type="xsd:string">***</Login><Password xsi:type="xsd:string">***</P"...
      [1] =>
      string(52) "https://***/wsedi/services/EDIServiceSoap"
      [2] =>
      string(50) "https://***/wsedi/services/Send#ExecSQL"
      [3] =>
      int(1)
      [4] =>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  [1] =>
  array(6) {
    'file' =>
    string(29) "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php"
    'line' =>
    int(29)
    'function' =>
    string(10) "__soapCall"
    'class' =>
    string(10) "SoapClient"
    'type' =>
    string(2) "->"
    'args' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(7) "ExecSQL"
      [1] =>
      array(4) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post full stack trace of `SOAPFault`?

Comment: firewall? php-in-server will appear to be coming from a different executable than php-at-cli, and the cli version may not be permitted

Comment: firewall is turned off